# Duvida Autocomplete com .Blur

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho o código abaixo, e estou usando o autocomplete com o Blur para que ao usuário digitar o código de barras, ele consulte no banco e preencha os campos automaticamente.
Como não tenho domínio do javascript não consegui sair disso.

```
 //+ produtos
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var max_fields = 32;
            var wrapper = $(".produto"); //Fields wrapper
            var add_button = $(".add-camera"); //Add button ID

            var x = 0; //initlal text box count
            $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
                e.preventDefault();
                if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                    x++; //text box increment

                    $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group">\
                                        <input type="text" name="idproduto' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter idproduto" id="idproduto' + x + '"  Size="1" placeholder="Id" readonly />\
                                        <input type="text" name="ean' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="ean' + x + '"  Size="10" placeholder="ean"  />\
                                        <input type="text" name="nome' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="nome' + x + '"  Size="50" placeholder="Nome" required autofocus />\
                                        <input type="text" name="referencia' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="referencia' + x + '"  Size="10" placeholder="Referencia" readonly />\
                                        <input type="text" name="quantidade' + x + '" id="quantidade' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter quantidade" Size="2" placeholder="Quant." onchange="somarTotais()"  />\
                                        <input type="text" name="valorunitario' + x + '" id="valorunitario' + x + '" onkeydown="FormataMoeda(this,10,event)" onkeypress="return maskKeyPress(event)" class="form-control produtoCounter valorunitario" Size="5"  />\
                                        <input type="text" name="desconto' + x + '" id="desconto' + x + '" value="0" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" placeholder="Desc" />\
                                        <input type="text" name="estoque' + x + '" id="estoque' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter estoque" size="6" placeholder="Estoque" readonly />\
                                        <input type="text" name="desconto1' + x + '" id="desconto1' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto1" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" style="display: none;" />\
                                        <a href="#" class="remove-camera">Remover</a>\
                                    </div>');

                    $("#nome" + x).autocomplete({
                        source: "produtos.php",
                        minLength: 2,
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('#idproduto' + x).val(ui.item.idproduto);
                            idproduto = ui.item.idproduto;
                            $('#nome' + x).val(ui.item.nome);
                            produto = ui.item.nome;
                            $('#ean' + x).val(ui.item.codigo);
                            $('#referencia' + x).val(ui.item.referencia);
                            $('#valorunitario' + x).val(ui.item.valorunitario);
                                         
                        }
                        });

                    // verificar codigo de barras
        $(function () {
            $("#ean" + x).bind("change paste keyup", function() {
                var total = $(this).val().length;
                if(total == 13){
                    $(this).blur();
                    $('#idproduto' + x).val(ui.item.idproduto);
                    $('#nome' + x).val(ui.item.nome);
                    $('#ean' + x).val(ui.item.codigo);
                    $('#referencia' + x).val(ui.item.referencia);
                    $('#valorunitario' + x).val(ui.item.valorunitario);
                    $('#desconto1' + x).val(ui.item.desconto);
                    $('#estoque' + x).val(ui.item.quantidade);
                    $('#minimo' + x).val(ui.item.minimo);
                }
            }).blur(function() {
                var total = $(this).val().length;
                if(total == 13){
                    $('#idproduto' + x).val(ui.item.idproduto);
                    $('#nome' + x).val(ui.item.nome);
                    $('#ean' + x).val(ui.item.codigo);
                    $('#referencia' + x).val(ui.item.referencia);
                    $('#valorunitario' + x).val(ui.item.valorunitario);
                    $('#desconto1' + x).val(ui.item.desconto);
                    $('#estoque' + x).val(ui.item.quantidade);
                    $('#minimo' + x).val(ui.item.minimo);
                }
            }).
            autocomplete({
                autoFocus: true,
                source: "codigos.php"
            });
        });
//fim da procura codigos de barras
                }
        });
            $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove-camera", function (e) { //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
                somarTotais();
                document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = false; // Habilitar
                x--; //text box decrement
            })
        });

//Busca BD

$return_arr = array();

if ($con) {
    $fetch = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM produtos where ean = $termo AND produtos.ativo = 1 ORDER BY idproduto DESC LIMIT 0 ,50");
  
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        $row_array['nome'] = utf8_encode($row['nome']);
        $idproduto = $row['idproduto'];
        $row['nome'] = utf8_encode($row['nome']);
      
        array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
    }
}
   mysqli_close($con);
  echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor a existência dos campos acima do `autocomplete`? Se for o que estou pensando existe um modo mais simples para isso, mas preciso de mais informações. Suponho que ao digitar o código você queira que os campos `#idproduto` ou `#valorunitario`, por exemplo, sejam automaticamente preenchidos, seria isso mesmo?

Comment: Adicionei o restante do código.

Comment: O usuário pode buscar pelo nome do produto ou pelo código de barras? Ou ele precisa primeiro buscar o nome e depois busca o código de barras? Estou perguntando pq em uma parte você busca pelo no nome do produto e em outra você busca o CB, ficou um pouco redundante, pois as duas funções preenchem os mesmo campos, talvez você possa validar o CB com um get dentro do select ao buscar pelo nome.

Comment: Sim, ele pode buscar ou pelo nome ou pelo código, mas não consegui fazer com que ele fizesse a busca no mesmo campo, buscando ou pelo nome ou pelo código, por conta disso, separei a busca em dois campos.

Comment: Para buscar pelos dois no mesmo campo você tem que mexer na sua query que busca no do banco de dados que retorna os produtos. Qual banco você está usando? Estou fazendo essa perguntas pois seu código tem uma ideia boa, mas ele ficou complexo de entender e acredito que ele possa ser simplificado.

Comment: Acredito que possa sim, mas lhe confesso que ainda não tenho o domínio desejável, apesar de me esforçar e fazer bastante leitura.
Utilizo o mysql .

Comment: Me da só um minuto que posto duas possíveis soluções para você e vamos trocando ideia!

Comment: A ideia é a seguinte, faço a leitura do código de barras, ele procura no BD, se encontra ele preenche os outros campos automaticamente. Mas o produto pode não ter um código de barras cadastrado, então o usuário poderia fazer a busca pelo nome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa seria a solução usando os dois campos separadamente, levando em conta a informação de que o produto pode não ter um código de barras atrelado, dessa forma se você buscar pelo nome preenche os campos e se você buscar no campo código de barras também preenche os campos.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    //+ produtos
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        var max_fields = 32;
        var wrapper = $(".produto"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add-camera"); //Add button ID

        var x = 0; //initlal text box count
        
        $(add_button).click(function (e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                
                x++; //text box increment

                $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group">\
                    <input type="text" name="idproduto' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter idproduto" id="idproduto' + x + '"  Size="1" placeholder="Id" readonly />\
                    <input type="text" name="ean' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="ean' + x + '"  Size="10" placeholder="ean"  />\
                    <input type="text" name="nome' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="nome' + x + '"  Size="50" placeholder="Nome" required />\
                    <input type="text" name="referencia' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter" id="referencia' + x + '"  Size="10" placeholder="Referencia" readonly />\
                    <input type="text" name="quantidade' + x + '" id="quantidade' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter quantidade" Size="2" placeholder="Quant." onchange="somarTotais()"  />\
                    <input type="text" name="valorunitario' + x + '" id="valorunitario' + x + '" onkeydown="FormataMoeda(this,10,event)" onkeypress="return maskKeyPress(event)" class="form-control produtoCounter valorunitario" Size="5"  />\
                    <input type="text" name="desconto' + x + '" id="desconto' + x + '" value="0" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" placeholder="Desc" />\
                    <input type="text" name="estoque' + x + '" id="estoque' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter estoque" size="6" placeholder="Estoque" readonly />\
                    <input type="text" name="desconto1' + x + '" id="desconto1' + x + '" class="form-control produtoCounter desconto1" Size="2" onchange="somarTotais()" style="display: none;" />\
                    <a href="#" class="remove-camera">Remover</a>\
                </div>');

                $("#nome" + x).autocomplete({
                    source: "produtos.php",
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        
                        $('#idproduto' + x).val(ui.item.idproduto);
                        $('#nome' + x).val(ui.item.nome);
                        $('#ean' + x).val(ui.item.codigo);
                        $('#referencia' + x).val(ui.item.referencia);
                        $('#valorunitario' + x).val(ui.item.valorunitario);

                    }
                });

                $("#ean" + x).on('blur',function(){

                    var seletor = $(this); //Armazeno o Seletor;
                    var ean = seletor.val(); //Pego o valor do campo;

                    var total = seletor.val().length;
                    if(total == 13){ // Só consulta se todo código for digitado;

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'codigos.php',
                            type: 'GET', // As variaveis são enviadas como $_GET;
                            dataType: 'JSON', // E o retorno dever ser feito em JSON;
                            data: {ean:ean}, // Variaveis;
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                
                                // Pode ser colocado um loading aqui, exemplo;
                                $('#nome' + x).val('Carregando...');

                            },
                            success: function(data){

                                console.log(data);

                                $('#idproduto' + x).val(data.idproduto);
                                $('#nome' + x).val(data.nome);
                                $('#ean' + x).val(data.codigo);
                                $('#referencia' + x).val(data.referencia);
                                $('#valorunitario' + x).val(data.valorunitario);
                                $('#desconto1' + x).val(data.desconto);
                                $('#estoque' + x).val(data.quantidade);
                                $('#minimo' + x).val(data.minimo);

                            },
                            error: function(xhr,er) {
                                console.log('O sistema retornou um erro código ' + xhr.status);
                            }
                        });

                    }

                });

            }

        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove-camera", function (e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            somarTotais();
            document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = false; // Habilitar
            x--; //text box decrement
        });

    });
</script>

<div class="produto"></div>
<button class="add-camera">Add Produto</button>
```

**codigos.php**

```
$return_arr = array();

if ($con) {
    $termo = $_GET['ean'];
    // O Código deve ser digitado totalmente para retornar o dado;
    $fetch = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM produtos where ean = $termo AND produtos.ativo = 1 ORDER BY idproduto DESC LIMIT 0 ,50");
  
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        
        $row_array['idproduto'] = utf8_encode($row['idproduto']);
        $row_array['nome'] = utf8_encode($row['nome']);
        $row_array['ean'] = utf8_encode($row['ean']);
        $row_array['referencia'] = utf8_encode($row['referencia']);
        $row_array['valorunitario'] = utf8_encode($row['valorunitario']);
        $row_array['desconto1'] = utf8_encode($row['desconto1']);
        $row_array['estoque'] = utf8_encode($row['estoque']);
        $row_array['minimo'] = utf8_encode($row['minimo']);
      
        array_push($return_arr, $row_array);

    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($return_arr);
exit();
```

Se for um sistema fora de uma intranet, sugir colocar uma validação neste arquivo que retorna os dados, para evitar acesso direto sem autenticação(senha/login)

Comment: A conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115128/discussion-on-answer-by-gnomo-escalate-duvida-autocomplete-com-blur)